# Symfony Form only returns objects instead of insertions

Tags: symfony, symfony-forms

I'm currently working on something like a survey/quiz in Symfony. To do so, I have a Question-Entity with an Description, and a Quiz-Entity, which has nothing special unity know except of a submit date.

The important thing is that I want to generate a dynamic form with a random dataset of questions from the db. My current FormType looks like this:

```
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
{
    $builder->addEventListener(FormEvents::PRE_SET_DATA, function(FormEvent $event) {
        $questions = $event->getData();
        $form = $event->getForm();

        $i = 0;

        foreach($questions as $question) {
            $form
                ->add('question'.$i, TextareaType::class,[
                    'label' => $question['description'],
                    'mapped' => false,
                ])
            ;
            $i++;
        }
        $form->add('submit', SubmitType::class);
    });
}
```

My controller:

```
/**
 * @Route("/new", name="new")
 */
public function newQuiz(Request $request)
{
    $result = $this->quizQuestionRepository->getRandomQuestion();
    $form = $this->createForm(QuestionFormType::class, $result);
    $form->handleRequest($request);

    if($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid()) {
        $data  = $form->getData();
        dd($data);
    }
    return $this->render('question/new.html.twig', [
        'form' => $form->createView()
    ]);
}
```

The Question-Entity:

```
/**
 * @ORM\Entity()
 * @ORM\Table(name="questions")
 */
class Question
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Id()
     * @ORM\Column(type="uuid", unique=true)
     */
    private string $id;
    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="text")
     */
    private string $description;
    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string")
     */
    private string $category;

    public function __construct()
    {
       $this->id = Uuid::uuid4()->toString();
    }

    // GETTERS AND SETTERS - NOTHING SPECIAL
}
```

But this doesn't work. For some reason, I get the questions objects returned, not the insertions from the textareas. Can someone help me out?

Comment: Could you add your entities to your question please.

Comment: of course, added it

Comment: Do you have a "Quiz" form type? what is the relation between a Quiz and Question? Di you try a CollectionType?